# multiply matrix by itself in python (H.W)

Tags: python

I need to write a program that multiply matrix (nXn) by itself.
I have to calculate the max and min during the process and not in the end.

this is my code:

```
import csv
import time

start= time.time()

matrix = [] 

with open('matrix.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    exc1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in exc1:
        matrix.append(row)

matrix_length=len(matrix)

min = 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
max = 0

result = [[None]*matrix_length for _ in range(matrix_length)]

for i in range(matrix_length):
   for j in range(matrix_length):
       for k in range(0,matrix_length):
           result[i][j] += int(matrix[i][k]) * int(matrix[k][j])
       if (int(result[i][j])<min):
               min = int(result[i][j])
       if (int(result[i][j])>max):
               max = int(result[i][j])    

done=time.time()

print("max:",max)
print("min:",min)
print(done-start)
```

this is the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-15-a8472dbf81c8>", line 24, in <module>
    result[i][j] += int(matrix[i][k]) * int(matrix[k][j])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

do you understand what is the problem?

Comment: Your result matrix is of type 'None'. Try initialize it to 0 instead of None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing your result matrix with None. Try this instead:

```
result = [[0]*matrix_length for _ in range(matrix_length)]
```